# code not working for bigger range of numbers

Tags: javascript, html

So my problem is that I wrote this code that takes two numbers and writes all numbers between those numbers (including the given two numbers). The code works for the numbers 4 and 7, it prints out "4 5 6 7" but when the 2nd number is a little bigger than the first number for example for the numbers 6 and 14 the code does nothing. If someone could explain to me why it is like this and how could I solve this problem I would-be so happy.

```js
function calculate() {
  var start = document.getElementById("number1").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("number2").value;
  var answer = "";
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    answer = answer + i + " ";
  }
  document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = answer;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number1">
<input type="number" id="number2">
<button onclick="calculate()">Pokaż</button>
<div id="answer2"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `value` property returns a string representing the value of the `value` attribute of a text field.
To compare `start` and `end` you need to convert them into numbers (*e.g.* with the [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) primitive wrapper), else the string `6` will be (alphabetically) greater than the string `14`.

```js
function calculate() {
  var start = Number(document.getElementById("number1").value);
  var end = Number(document.getElementById("number2").value);
  var answer = "";
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    answer = answer + i + " ";
  }
  document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = answer;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number1">
<input type="number" id="number2">
<button onclick="calculate()">Pokaż</button>
<div id="answer2"></div>
```

Comment: This solved the problem but can you explain why?

Comment: @DoğuşHamdi I explained why.

Comment: @DoğuşHamdi The string `6` is larger than the string `14`, when compared alphabetically, so your `for()` loop doesn't do anything. Compare: `console.log('6' > '14') (true)` and `console.log(6 > 14) (false)`

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see it, thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 2):

That's the alternative solution with parseInt in for

```js
function calculate() {
  var start = document.getElementById("number1").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("number2").value;
  var answer = "";
  for (var i = parseInt(start); i <= parseInt(end); i++) {
    answer = answer + i + " ";
  }
  document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = answer;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number1">
<input type="number" id="number2">
<button onclick="calculate()">Pokaż</button>
<div id="answer2"></div>
```

Comment: But why would you want to re-parse `end` for every value of `i`? I think it would make more sense to do it as part of assigning it to `end`. Also you should maybe mention that the input accepts hexadecimal (and potentially octal, depending on the browser/runtime) "numbers" this way, since you don't pass a second parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#description